# In vb.net, one of my literal controls cannot be accessed on PreRender

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I'm completely stumped by this problem.

I have:

```
Protected Overrides Sub CreateChildControls()

    Dim lcStartButtonText As New LiteralControl
    lcStartButtonText.ID = "lcStartButtonText"

    Dim lcCancelButtonText as New LiteralControl
    lcCancelButtonText.ID = "lcCancelButtonText"

    With Controls
        .Add(lcStartButtonText)
        .Add(lcCancelButtonText)
    End With
    MyBase.CreateChildControls()
End Sub
```

Then, so that I can access token replacement I'm populating the literal controls OnPreRender... Removing tokens for simplicity and manually adding text, it still does not work. Example:

```
Protected Overrides Sub OnPreRender(e As EventArgs)
    MyBase.OnPreRender(e)

    Dim lcStartButtonText As LiteralControl = FindControl("lcStartButtonText")
    lcStartButtonText.Text = "<span>Start</span>"

    Dim lcCancelButtonText As LiteralControl = FindControl("lcCancelButtonText")
    lcCancelButtonText.Text = "<span>Cancel</span>"
End Sub
```

What's happening is when the control is rendered the cancel is empty.

The above is a simple example. My code is long, but follows the same pattern for each literal control being rendered. I've double, triple, quadruple checked and copied and pasted to ensure no typos.

Because my example is simple, I'm mainly looking for advice as to what might be causing this based on someone else's experience who may have run into this problem.

I have like 30 literal controls and every one is working except the cancel one.

Any thoughts?

Thank you!

Comment: Two things come to mind but I dont expect either to help you. 1) The cancel button is inside another `NamingContainer` (like a GridView) so that it isn't accessible to `Page.FindControl` 2) You're adding the cancel button from another class instead of the page's codebehind.

Comment: @Jeff Thank you for your response, however the controls are setup the same. I mean I'm sure ~something~ must be wrong. I just can't figure it out.

Comment: ARGH! I found my problem!!! I was using the same literalcontrol twice in CreateChildControls!